# How to move the symbols in R legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to move the dotted line to the right so that (ideally) the centers of the boxes and the center of the line are aligned. I am using standard R plots (not ggplot or anything). The code I used for creating the legend so far is the following:

`legend("topright", legend=c("[0,1st quant.]","(1st quant., 2nd quant.]", "(2nd quant., 3rd quant.]", "(3rd quant., maximum]", "Poi(137.205) density"), fill=c(cols[-1],NA), lty=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,3),cex=0.8, box.lty = 0, border=c(1,1,1,1,"white"))`

Histogram the legend has to be adapted for
[image: Histogram the legend has to be adapted for]

Comment: thanks! How did you embedded the image inline?

Answer (score 0):

looking only for the doc, `xjust` argument for `legend` sets the legend justification.

Also, let me add another tip: before considering the legend, add a title to your plot, it's far more important ;)

Comment: Thanks! I got a title but I didn't include it to screenshot because its kind of sensible data

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer, maybe it will be helpful for others at some time.
Just add `x.intersp` to the legend and play around with the entry of the vector that should be moved. Increasing the number will move the symbol/line/box to the left.

```
legend("topright", 
       legend=c("[0,1st quant.]","(1st quant., 2nd quant.]", "(2nd quant., 3rd quant.]", "(3rd quant., maximum]", "Poi(137.205) density"), 
       fill=c(cols[-1],NA), lty=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,3),
       cex=0.8, box.lty = 0, border=c(1,1,1,1,"white"), 
       x.intersp = c(1,1,1,1,2.2))
```